# How to Render uploaded Excel file in JSP Page from a Temp Folder?

Tags: java, excel, spring, jsp

I am not clear of rendering the uploaded Excel sheet into JSP Page

Here is the sample code of Uploading Excel

importExcel.jsp

```
<body>
<form:form method="POST" action="fileUpload"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="upload">
 <div class="upload-files">
  <header>
   <p>
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="up">up</span>
    <span class="load">Load</span>
   </p>
  </header>
  <div class="body" id="drop">
   <i class="fa fa-file-text-o pointer-none" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <p class="pointer-none"><b>Drag and drop</b> files here <br /> or <a href="" id="triggerFile">browse</a> to begin the upload</p>
            <input type="file" name="xlsFile" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />
  </div>
  <footer>
   <div class="divider">
    <span><AR>FILES</AR></span>
   </div>
   <div class="list-files">
    <!--   template   -->
   </div>
            <button class="importar">UPDATE FILE</button>
  </footer>
 </div>
</div>


</form:form>
</body>
```

HomeController.java

```
@PostMapping("/fileUpload")
    public String getFileUploadResult(@RequestParam("xlsFile") MultipartFile multiPartFile )throws Exception{
        try {

            if(multiPartFile!=null && !multiPartFile.isEmpty()){
                byte[] fileBytes = multiPartFile.getBytes();
                if(fileBytes!=null){
                    System.out.println("multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename() :: "  +multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename());
                    Path internalPath=Paths.get(RAW_DATA_FILE_PATH+multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename());
                    if(internalPath!=null){
                        System.out.println("file written");
                        Files.write(internalPath,fileBytes);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("internalPath is null");
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("fileBytes is null");
                }
            }else{
                return "importExcel";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return "viewUploadedExcel";
    }
```

I am in need to View the uploaded Excel file in viewUploadedExcel.jsp file, Since I am in research of this to bring out the solution and not yet met the expectation.

**NOTE**: I am working on JSP and Spring

Comment: Please ask specific question about problem you met implementing this? What is your question? How to parse excel file? how to render table? You in fact ask for a tutorial which is offtopic here. Change the question to show some small problem you met and show your best efforts.

Comment: Hi stanislavL, My problem is how to view the Excel file in JSP page. Since I have gone through many blogs am not able to get solution. Could you help

Comment: The described problem is not for stackoverflow. The problem suitable for SO could be e.g. "I try to parse excel file with apache POI library and get error ... ". That's the problem SO can help to solve. Or "I parsed file and have a 2 dimensional array. cannot output the array to JSP with the rpoblem...". It's fine for SO and can be answered. In your case it's too broad. Break your problem in a list of smaller ones and post different questions for each of the relatively small problems.

Comment: ok stanislavL Thanks for your suggestion will follow up, So where can i get the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the mime/type in the response contentType to something like application/vnd.ms-excel, depending on the file format. Basing on file extension, xlsx would be application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet. Then just use out.write the content of the uploaded file.
Obviously, the rendering of the excel by the browser depends on the browser.

Comment: Hi ugo, If i do as you said, the file is downloading but i need to show the excel file inside the JSP page